# Some href links not clickable

Tags: html, materialize

I am working on a small project and faced one interesting problem (code below is simplified, but behavior is same). For some reason only Column4's URL is clickable whilst the rest is not. Do you have any idea what is a cause of the problem? I spent a lot of time by investigating the issue and it seems that input fields may be a problem, but I don't understand why.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-alpha.4/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="container">
<div class="navbar-fixed">
    <nav>
       <ul id="nav-mobile" class="left">
         <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
         <li>
   <div class="row" id="topbarsearch">
    <form name="myform" method="post">
     <div class="input-field">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">search</i>
                        <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" name="autocomplete-input">
                        <input type="submit" style="visibility: hidden;">
                        <ul class="autocomplete-content dropdown-content"></ul>
     </div>
                </form>
            </div>
         </li>
       </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<main>
 <table class="centered">
        <tr>
            <th><a href="#">Column1</a></th>
            <th><a href="#">Column2</a></th>
            <th><a href="#">Column3</a></th>
            <th><a href="#">Column4</a></th>
        </tr>
 </table>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perhaps something is blocking the links. Check with Chrome Console if something is in front of your links.

Comment: I've tested here, and in my screen `#nav-mobile` is in front of Column1 and Column2... I think this may be the problem.

Comment: I thought it may be some simple stupid mistake ... and it realy is :-) Thanks a lot

Comment: You are welcome! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The submit button in the form used for search caused the form, and therefore the entire menu bar, to be taller. The menu bar is "in front" of the rest of the page, so it blocks the first three columns even though there is nothing visible that would cause this.

To fix this problem, add `style="max-height: 64px;"` to the `<ul id="nav-mobile" class="left">` element, so that it becomes `<ul id="nav-mobile" class="left" style="max-height: 64px;">`. This allows the other three columns to be clicked. (tested in Chrome 77)

Update: Also, add `style="max-height: 64px; overflow: hidden"` to `<div class="input-field">`.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-alpha.4/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="container">
<div class="navbar-fixed">
    <nav>
       <ul id="nav-mobile" class="left" style="max-height: 64px;">
         <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
         <li>
   <div class="row" id="topbarsearch">
    <form name="myform" method="post">
     <div class="input-field" style="max-height: 64px; overflow: hidden">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">search</i>
                        <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" name="autocomplete-input">
                        <input type="submit" style="visibility: hidden;">
                        <ul class="autocomplete-content dropdown-content"></ul>
     </div>
                </form>
            </div>
         </li>
       </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<main>
 <table class="centered">
        <tr>
            <th><a href="#">Column1</a></th>
            <th><a href="#">Column2</a></th>
            <th><a href="#">Column3</a></th>
            <th><a href="#">Column4</a></th>
        </tr>
 </table>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This solution helps only partially. But there is still overlap of hidden submit button. I had to set limit also for `<div class="row" id="topbarsearch" style="max-height: 64px;">` and to change submit input to button: `<button type="submit" style="visibility: hidden;"></button>`. And it works now.